# Present Perfect and Simple Past in the same sentence

Tags: present-perfect, simple-past

I have a short and simple question for you.
I know that in some circumstances I can use the Present Perfect and the Simple Past in the same sentence, but I am wondering if the following example is the case.

"During my studies I ***have taken part*** in several group projects, both in Italy and abroad, which ***required*** the use of Office Suite."

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can use both here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is correct.
In the first clause there is the Present Perfect Tense because you are still  a student and may take some more projects before your graduation. This usage is called 'unfinished Past'. 
In the second clause there is the Past Simple Tense because you inform about certain past experiences. This usage is called 'finished Past'.